# Is it possible to implement reverseOrder() method using Comparator<T>?

Tags: java, comparator

I have been analyzing with Comparator interface in Java SE 8. Now, I am interested to know that how could I use `reverseOrder()` method using a class which implements the `Comparator<T>` interface. I wrote to a example program to check that out.

```
class NaturalOrderString implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }               
} 

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Comparator<String> mycom= new NaturalOrderString();

      mycom.reverseOrder(); // can't use this
   }
}
```

So, now I should be able to use all the methods associated with `Comparator` Interface. But surprisingly whey I type `mycom.` then there comes no suggestion for reverseOrder() method. Why ? 
The class  `NaturalOrderString` implements `Comparator<T>` .

So, I should accept `mycom` object to access `reverseOrder()` method. Isn't it ?

Moreover, I came to know that sorting in lists are occurred  using **natural ordering**. So, using the **Collection** class I could access `reverseOrder()` method. So, preceding my example I could happily write

```
Collections.reverseOrder(mycom); // that's fine.
```

But my question is why I can't use `reverseOrder()` using a object of a class which implements `Comparator<T>` ? And, since we can't access it why Java include `reverseOrder()`method in `Comparator<T>` interface ?

Or, if it's really possible to access `reverseOrder()` through **mycom** object regarding my code, please give me an example of it.

Comment: Because `reverseOrder` is a static method.

Comment: So , can I use Comparator.reverseOrder() ??

Comment: What is the point of Static method in a interface ?? Interfaces in java has to physical instances? right ? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: `Comparator` has `reversed()` as default method.  So you can do `mycom.reversed(); ` instead of `mycom.reverseOrder(); `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically reverseOrder() method will return a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering.

Firstly, following your question, since reverseOrder() is a **`static method`** you can't use it like mycom.reverseOrder(). You have to use like Comparot.reverseOrder().
Following your code. I created a ArrayList to demonstrate and use Comparator.reverseOrder()

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<String> people= new ArrayList<String>();
    people.add("Sam");
    people.add("Bob");
    people.add("Andrew");
    people.add("Michel");
    people.add("Abe");
    people.add("John");

    Comparator<String> mycom= new NaturalOrderString();

    Collections.sort(people); // this will sort the people array list in natural order

    Collections.sort(people,Comparator.reverseOrder()); // Here's your desired method it will reverse the natural order as documentation.

     }
  }
```

Hope you are now clear with this concept.

Comment: But, why Comparator.reverseOrder() doesn't work independently ? @W.Jack

Answer (score 3):

Basically a lot of magic is possible here.

In order to reverse sorting, you simply need to "reverse" the result of the comparation.

You can study these [foils](http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/D4_Wiedeking.pdf). They are written in German, but there isn't much text there - and the code is all java. The presentation gives some lambda basics; to then explain how you can use lambdas and method references to develop a whole system where you sort/reverse sort streams; using "accessor" objects to retrieve whatever properties from the things you intend to sort.

For example leading to:

```
interface Comparator<T> {
  public int compare(T a, T b);
  public default Comparator<T> reversed() {
    return (a, b) –> compare(b, a) ;
}
```

Now one can implement that interface, and reverse sorting comes for free.

Answer (score 2):

The `Comparator.reverseOrder()` method simply delegates to `Collections.reverseOrder()` and `Collections.reverseOrder()` simply returns a comparator which implements reverse natural ordering.

What you are trying to do is as simple as this:

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) 
{
    int d = o1.compareTo(o2);
    return -d;
```

which can also be achieved with `myComparator.reversed()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Comparator.reverseOrder` is a static method.

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> **[8.4.8]** A class does not inherit static methods from its superinterfaces.

If you want to use this method, you can just call it as `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.  However, it sounds like that's not what you actually want - use the non-static `reversed()` instead.

Comment: So, what actually happen when i write Comparator.reverseOrder() . What is the point of reverseOrder() a interface which has no physical instances.

Comment: @Pointer - It's a convenience method that gives you a reversed natural ordering comparator.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use Comparator.reverseOrder()

Yes, of course you can. It's just not immediately obvious how you might use it because the compiler infers a lot of information.

The signature is:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder()
```

So as you can see, it takes a generic type, which must implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). It's somewhat more strict than that: it requires the type to be comparable to either itself or one of its super types. We *couldn't* get a reverse comparator for Apple, using these definitions:

```
public class Orange { }
public class Apple implements Comparable<Orange> { /* methods */ }
```

`reverseOrder` takes no arguments but returns us a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) of the type we pass in. You can use it like so:

```
Comparator<Foo> reverseCompatator = Comparator.<Foo>reverseOrder();
```

Here's a full, compilable example:

```
// Simply wraps an integer value
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>
{
    private final Integer value;

    Foo(final Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Foo that) {
        // use standard integer comparison (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,...)
        return this.value.compareTo(that.value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo " + value;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // create a list
        List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(new Foo(1), new Foo(3), new Foo(5));

        // sort the list in reverse
        foos.sort(
            Comparator.<Foo>reverseOrder()
        );

        System.out.println(foos);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> [Foo 5, Foo 3, Foo 1]

In practice you can remove `<Foo>` from `Comparator.<Foo>` because the compiler is able to work out what you need.